# Port forwarding / UPnP issues with media server software

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, plex

I am facing a bizarre issue where port forwarding on my home router works perfectly well for most applications, but specifically doesn't work for media server software I've tried it with (Plex and Emby). Since it fails for multiple applications I'm guessing it is a network issue, even though for other applications it works fine.

Everything works as expected inside the network with SSH, both media servers, and some other applications all accessible on the various ports they are configured on.

Port forwarding on the router is easy to set up, and works fine for SSH and some other applications with web user interfaces. It works whether forwarding the same port or a custom one (e.g. `22 -> 22`, or `23 -> 22`). It also works whether configured manually or using UPnP. However with two specific applications (Plex and Emby) attempting to access them on the external port just times out.

I can see that the port is open by using a port scanner on the internet, and indeed I can even see it working to the extent that the basic URI gets transformed into the correct full URL for the application's home page as I would expect (e.g. putting *100.2.3.4:1234* in a web browser becomes *http://100.2.3.4:1234/web/index.html*), however the page simply fails to load.

When running only Plex I assumed this was probably an issue with the application itself, so I installed Emby as well, however it has exactly the same issue, making me think it is more likely to be some kind of network configuration issue. So far as I can tell both applications are configured correctly to receive remote connections.

Entering either the internal or external address into a browser while within the network works perfectly well.

I have DDNS set up, but the behaviour is the same whether accessing through DDNS or with my current external IP.

My router is an ASUS RT-AC66U running stock firmware version 3.0.0.4.384_32799. Behind it is a server running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, which is running all the applications in question.

Any ideas for debugging this would be gratefully received!

Comment: Have you configured Plex as described [here](https://support.plex.tv/articles/200931138-troubleshooting-remote-access/)? (Shorter version [here](https://forums.plex.tv/t/ports-to-allow-inbound-and-outbound/196581).) Manual works better than UPnP.

Comment: Yes, thank you, sadly I have already been through all of that troubleshooting...

Comment: Try to temporarily disable your antivirus and firewall, as a test.

Comment: No AV running on it (it’s a Linux server), and no firewall on the server. Disabling the firewall on the router makes no difference.

Comment: I find it hard to explain this behavior. I wonder if you did disable UPnP for Plex.

Comment: Even if Plex were misconfigured, you would expect Emby to work. Also they both still fail when manually forwarded with UPnP disabled on the router :/

Comment: Yes, but is UPnP disabled for these apps, or are they trying to open the ports?

Comment: They’re trying to open them, and in fact they’re succeeding: using an online port scanner shows that the ports are open (and that the ports either side are closed). The applications are definitely successfully opening the ports, they’re just not responding the way they’re supposed to when contacted on the port... The way they correctly do when contacted on that same port from within the network. It’s baffling. Thank you for your help with this.